# Fetch LinkedIn Data using JS givs error "message": "Unknown authentication scheme"

Tags: linkedin-api

I have followed this exemple https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/fetch-linkedin-data-using-javascript to fetch data like updates/post from a company specific .

I am getting the following error.

{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unknown authentication scheme",
  "requestId": "MXRLWYPBNU",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1539160527230
}

The company have added my profile as a company admin so I should have the authentication to get the data.

What am I doing wrong ? 
    Alright here is my code:`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: 8616po0krrhh2k
scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad,
</script>


$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
if (settings.url == "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate") {
    settings.url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize"
}});

function onLinkedInLoad() {
IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth());}

function onSuccess(data) {
console.log(data); }


function onError(error) {
console.log(error);
}
function onLinkedInAuth() {
var cpnyID = 86104; //the Company ID for which we want updates
IN.API.Raw("/companies/" + cpnyID + "/updates?event-type=status- 
update&start=0&count=10&format=json").result(displayCompanyUpdates);

console.log("After auth");
}

function displayCompanyUpdates(result) {
var div = document.getElementById("displayUpdates");
var el = "<ul>";
var resValues = result.values[0];
for (var i in resValues) {
var share = resValues[i].updateContent.companyStatusUpdate.share;
    var isContent = share.content;
    var isTitled = isContent,
        isLinked = isContent,
        isDescription = isContent,
        isThumbnail = isContent,
        isComment = isContent;
    if (isTitled) {
        var title = isContent.title;
    } else {
        var title = "News headline";
    }
    var comment = share.comment;
    if (isLinked) {
        var link = isContent.shortenedUrl;
    } else {
        var link = "#";
    }
    if (isDescription) {
        var description = isContent.description;
    } else {
        var description = "No description";
    }

    if (share) {
    var content = "< a target = '_blank' href = " + link + " > " + comment + " 
    </a><br>";

     el += "<li><div>" + content + "</div></li>";
    }
    console.log(share);
}
 el += "</ul>";
 document.getElementById("displayUpdates").innerHTML = el;
}




<div id="displayUpdates"></div>`
```

Comment: show us your code, the link isnt a good source because we cant look if you made a mistake.

Comment: Aright, I added my code in the answer below.

Comment: could you also edit in what permissions your linkedin developer account has ?

Comment: Do you mean "Default Application Permissions" in my application ?

Comment: yes, do you have all of them ?

Comment: yes, all of them checked

Comment: check my answer i posted below.

Comment: Yes, I will try it soon. Hope it fix the problem :)

Comment: I tried to change the scope  to rw_company_admin and I am still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

well one obvious problem i see with your code, is that you added the wrong scopes for the call you want to make.

for company API calls you need the following scope : `rw_company_admin`